# Display dynamic data with JSON API Jquery

Tags: api

I've been reading about Javascript for 2 days now and I'm still confused. I'm familiar with HTML and CSS. My goal is to display a dynamic value on my website. The data will be from an API call using JSON.

The URL i'm using displays info like this

```
{
"error" : 0,
"error_message" : "-",
"amount" : 35.63000
}
```

What I want to do is take the "amount" variable and display it on my website. So far I have managed to jumble a bunch of code together that barely makes sense to me. I'm probably using all the wrong syntax so I will continue to try and figure this out myself. All this does it displays a static variable in "div1". What is the best way to convert the variable from the API call to show instead.

```
$.getJSON('https://www.amdoren.com/api/currency.php?api_key=jbqe5fH8AykJTFbnyR7Hf3d2n3KVQR&from=USD&to=THB&amount=1', function(data) {
  //data is the JSON string
});

////
var $items = $('#amount')
var obj = {}
$items.each(function() {
  obj[this.id] = $(this).val();
})

var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
///

var obj = [ {
  "error": 0,
  "error_message": "-",
  "amount": 35.60000  ///THIS IS OBVIOUSLY STATIC...
}]
var tbl = $("<table/>").attr("id", "mytable");
$("#div1").append(tbl);
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  var tr = "<tr>";
  var td3 = "<td>" + obj[i]["amount"] + "</td></tr>";

  $("#mytable").append(tr + td3);

}
```